# How everyone monitor RDS PostgreSQL error log?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitor, rds

I'm new to RDS and previously have been administrated non-cloud database. It's common monitor database error log and monitors the texts. But when it comes to RDS Postgres, there is no native service that monitors log file.
(I know now RDS MySQL/MariaDB has a functionality to publish to CloudWatch logs, but RDS Postgres still cannot do it)

I guess basic scenario if we want to monitor RDS log files within AWS services, create Lambda function that download error log files periodically and save to S3 buckets. And parse it and if find error message, notify some chat service(like slack).

But it is not realtime and gonna call a lot of API call.

I'm wondering how people deal with monitoring log file.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon provides (since 12/2018) publishing logs from RDS for PostgreSQL databases to Amazon CloudWatch Logs in Amazon RDS. Supported logs include PostgreSQL system logs and upgrade logs. [1]

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/12/amazon-rds-supports-postgresql-logfiles-publish-to-amazon-cloudwatch-logs/